# Where is the background photo used by Office 365 taken?

Tags: usa, photography, locate-this

If you login to Office 365 on http://login.microsoftonline.com, you see following picture.

[image: Office 365 login screen]

Does anyone know where it was taken. I could not find it with Google.

Comment: Looks very similar to the roads near Del Perro Pier in GTA V!

Comment: @lightswitchr that is true! Los Santos (GTA V's city) is based on Los Angeles. You can visit most of Santa Monica and Malibu.

Comment: The pic taken for 365 reminds me of San Diego

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Santa Monica California. I googled the name on the bottom left of the image and came across [this post](http://www.alexhungry.com/2014/06/office-365-sign-in-picture-location.html). The post says Malibu, but I think Malibu is further up the coast.

For some reason, I can't find the name of the road on google maps, so had to resort to using bing...

[image]

Very close to Santa Monica pier.

The view is looking north, overlooking the Pacific Coast Highway, from the bridge that leads to Santa Monica Pier.  The bluffs on the right are the edge of famous Palisades Park, and the western terminus of Route 66.  The building at far right is on Wilshire Blvd.

[Google streetview link](https://www.google.com/maps/@34.0108546,-118.4955922,3a,16.8y,319.94h,87.56t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sRtxcYJGAv-kOIzlDUl_DXQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656).

Comment: Nice. This name was not visible when my browser was maximized but I could see it upon changing its aspect ratio.

Comment: I looked it up on google images and chose the largest scale image I can find, which had it in and readable.

Comment: It is the Pacific Coast Highway, you see this view just after you come out of the tunnel from the Santa Monica Freeway. You're correct at this being Santa Monica still.

Comment: but *of course* you had to use Microsoft Bing :)

Comment: @d3vid That's approximately the second time in my life I've used bing. But moomat ahiko way isn't on google maps. Strange. Bing isn't noted for having useful information on it

Comment: Bing maps is pretty powerful btw.

Comment: It's funny, I instantly new it was near LA because it looks exactly like the road in GTA V you always take to go down the PCH from Los Santos.

Comment: About seven years ago in a Microsoft-owned building, I asked for directions to a nearby library.  After fighting with Bing for a few minutes, the guy looked around, said "Don't tell anybody I used the "G" word, and then he opened Google Maps.

Answer (score 20):

This photo was taken in Santa Monica, California, [from the bridge leading to the pier](https://goo.gl/maps/2bXjRGPSngw), which is named Colorado Avenue.

You can see [the same angle from Street View](https://goo.gl/maps/sAL4FWaQjmM2).